# How do I use Faust2Juce to convert faust.dsp to Jucer Project?

Tags: signal-processing

How do I use Faust2Juce to convert faust.dsp to Jucer Project?

Faust creates its code and UI from its own functional language , how do I continuously integrate to JUCE project?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the faust compiler you can use within terminal:

```
faust2juce -standalone "Example.dsp"
```

...to get a standalone project.

```
faust2juce --help
```

Will give you a more extensive list of commands.

Alternatively use the [online compiler](https://faust.grame.fr/onlinecompiler/), set the architecture to JUCE and then you can download the exec file (a producer project) from there.

[Here is a github link to the architecture for more info.](https://github.com/grame-cncm/faust/tree/master-dev/architecture/juce)